# How to calculate binocular overlap

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

I have two cameras of which I know focal length, principal point, rotation and position. The cameras are in an ideal parallel stereo system.

I want to know with as few calculations as possible how much the images of these cameras overlap (let's say a percentage).

I am trying to follow a guide called [Creating correct stereo pairs from any raytracer](http://paulbourke.net/stereographics/stereorender/), but I cannot find how to set `aperture` and `eye separation` to find `delta`.

Can I do it with my current data? Or is there a better way to know how much the camera images overlap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at [image stitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching) algorithms. Even though you don't want to actually combine the images into one, that's still essentially what you're doing.

You might even be able to use an off-the-shelf stitching algorithm to get a rough measure. e.g. If the stitched image is 100 pixels wide, and your two source images are 80 pixels wide, then horizontally you have a 60 pixel overlap.